# Filesystem for UNIX (Solaris, FreeBSD, Linux)

Tags: linux, filesystems, freebsd, solaris, openindiana

I have some Linux (Arch/Fedora/Ubuntu), FreeBSD and solaris (open indiana) desktop machines. What is the best filesystem that can be used in all of them. I want to use it in some external hard drives. The more feature (like ZFS's snapshotting) the filesystem has,  the better. (I think FAT is off the desk.)

External modules are ok as long as they are open-source.

My best bets are:

- [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS): Excellent  for Solaris and FreeBSD. But Linux has problem with it. (I have seen some third party modules but don't know whether they are in production quality).
- [Btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs): Works in Linux. But not in others.

Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: I don't get why this question has been closed. Finding an advanced filesystem being shareable between FreeBSD, Linux and Solaris is NOT, in my opinion, "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet".

Answer (score 2):

I'm sharing ZFS pools between Linux and Solaris with no issues. The only pitfall is you must create pools and file systems under the OS supporting the lower version of them, usually Linux, to be able to import/mount them everywhere.